# Parallelizing some LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

How can I make this code run in parallel?

```
List<Crop> crops = new List<Crop>();
//Get up to 10 pages of data.
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    //i is basically used for paging.
    XDocument document = XDocument.Load(string.Format(url, i));

    crops.AddRange(from c in document.Descendants("CropType")
                   select new Crop
                   {
                       //The data here.
                   });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you'd want to parallelize that, I suspect the overheads will bog your program down since you aren't doing anything really significant.  But for a translation, I suppose this would do.  I don't know what you want parallel so assuming you want the loop to run in parallel:

```
var crops =
    ParallelEnumerable.Range(1, 9)
        .SelectMany(i =>
            XDocument.Load(string.Format(url, i))
                     .Descendants("CropType")
                     .Select(c => new Crop
                      {
                          // The data here
                      })
         )
        .ToList();
```

Comment: @Danny: Yeah, I kinda wish the team made it a bit more intuitive to use and made the second parameter the upper limit, rather than the amount of values to generate like it is typically used in loops.  Then if you forget about it, it can bite you in the butt.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
var list = (from i in ParallelEnumerable.Range(1, 10)
            from c in XDocument.Load(string.Format(url, i))
                               .Descendants("CropType")
            select new Crop
            {
                //The data here.
            }).ToList();
```

That's basically the same as Jeff M's code, but in query expression format.

Two things to note:

- Your original code actually only produces *9* documents, not 10. Adjust my code to suit
- The results will *not* necessarily be in the original order. If you need ordering, use the [`AsOrdered`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413357.aspx) method.

Comment: +1 Oh I don't know there is a `ParallelEnumerable.Range`, I'm using `Enumerable.Range` and then `AsParallel`, LOL.