# Calling same method multiple times async

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I am building an MVC app that loops through an XML doc that includes some Urls, and does a get against those URLs. The doc can contain up to 400+ Urls, so doing a get one at a time is quite a delay for the user, so I am looking to do them in parallel.

Here is the basic structure of the method that does the work that I would like to refactor

```
List<CustomObject> finalList = new List<CustomObject>();
// at this point, list is populated with urls
foreach (string url in list)
{
   XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
   XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
   xmlDoc.Load(reader);
   //below method processes the XML and adds it to the List of custom objects
   finalList.AddRange(ProcessXML(xmlDoc));
}
```

Basically, what I would like to do is spin up a few threads to decrease the amount of time required to loop through the Doc and do the load (which is what takes the most time obviously).

Is there an easy way to do this that doesn't eat up resources? If so, how should it be structured. Let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: Your question is broad it hard to get what taking most of the time the foreach or the get of the url which i do not see foreach async and async in foreach will give you a big incosistency

Comment: Interesting idea, spinning up threads wouldn't be to difficult, however I'm curious about your idea of multiple threads looping through the same document. That would create duplicates in your resulting list would it not? Usually would use multiple threads if you were parsing different documents at the same time, instead of multiple threads parsing one document.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5114554/2563028

Comment: @mituw16 I would have to do a unique at the end to be safe yes, but that is quick in memory, so I am not too worried about it. I am more interested in being able to do multiple GETs async

Comment: @Isaac Levin you better of reading all urls in the list and then you can process the urls async after you get them

Comment: @IsaacLevin True true, no argument from me there. But making the parsing go in parallel would not speed it up in this case. Say you spin up 3 threads to do this, all three threads would start from row 1 and start parsing. Unless you dynamically split the file into chunks first, and then parse the chunks in parallel, async isn't going to help you here.

Comment: @COLDTOLD I am not following. I have a list of Urls, thats not the issue. The issue is I have to do GETs on all those Urls and  that is what I want to async.

Comment: take a look at this it might be what you want http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155756.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
        class WorkItem
        {
            public string Uri { get; set; }
            public byte[] Data { get; set; }
        }


        var items = new List<WorkItem>();

        // first do the parsing as you parsing 
        foreach (var urlFound in yourXmlDoc)
        {
            items.Add(new WorkItem{Uri = url});
        }

        // then the actual work itself
        Parallel.ForEach(items, item => {
            item.Data = GetUrlData(item.Uri);
        });
```

What this does is:
First gets all URLs from your XML document and this you have to do yourself as you didn't provide any information about this.
For every URL found, an instance of WorkItem will be created, containing the actual URL/URI and is added to a list.
Then, using Parallel.ForEach() does the work. Have a look at the anonymous method: GetUrlData(), this method you have implement as well. The return type would be a byte array or whatever.
The advantage of this is, that you do not have to worry about synchronizing access to the list

BTW:
I've never see one who did a multi-threaded parsing of a XML file. Which is indeed not that simple because it is a hierarchical data structure